# Maintain thread safety while preventing deadlock from possibly synchronous callback

Tags: java, multithreading, asynchronous, thread-safety, synchronous

I have an API like the following, where `Baz` is the worker implementation.
This `Bar` needs to be thread-safe, and this gets tricky when interacting with Baz's callbacks.

The current baz instance needs to be referenced in the callback (which can be called on a worker thread or synchronously).
The comments should show the problem:

```
final class Bar {
  final Lock lock = new ReentrantLock();
  Baz baz; // Guarded by lock.

  void run() { // Called by any thread.
    lock.lock();
    if (baz.isRunning()) {
      lock.unlock();
      return;
    }
    baz = new Baz();
    // If it unlocks here, the next line may execute on the wrong Baz.
    // If it doesn't unlock here, there will be a deadlock when done() is called synchronously.
    // lock.unlock();
    baz.run(new Baz.Callback() { // May be called synchronously or by Baz worker thread.
      @Override
      public void done() {
        lock.lock();
        baz = new Baz();
        lock.unlock();
      }
    });
  }
}
```

Is there a good way to make this work correctly while also not causing a deadlock?

Edit: more succinctly:

```
final class Foo {
  final Lock lock = new ReentrantLock();

  void run() {
    lock.lock();
    worker.enqueue(new Callback() {
      @Override void complete() {
        lock.lock(); // Could cause deadlock.
      }
    });
    lock.unlock();
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Not sure to completelly get what you are trying to achieve, but maybe this is what you are looking for?

```
final class Bar {
    final Lock lock = new ReentrantLock();
    Baz baz = new Baz();

    void run() {
        if (!lock.tryLock()) {
            return;
        }
        try {
            CountdownLatch callbackFlag = new CountdownLatch(1);
            baz.run(new Baz.Callback() {
                @Override
                public void done() {
                    callbackFlag.countDown();
                }
            });
            try {
                callbackFlag.await(); // better use overloaded method with max timeout waiting. you don't probably want to wait forever
                baz = new Baz(); // do you really want to reinit Baz on each execution?
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                // decide what you want to happen here
            }
        } finally {
            lock.unlock();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: The baz assignment needs to be in the callback, though.

Comment: why should it be referenced in the callback? the code i posted ensures baz is not reinit until callback is finished

Comment: in any case if you really needed, you can just move that line of code to the callback; everything will be all right anyway and thread-safety will be ok.